# QTransform::setRotation with Q_PROPERTY

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I have the problem that i want to set a Q_PROPERTY macro for my own class inherits by QGraphicsPixmapItem. So i my first property where i set the position works very well, but the second one where i want to set a rotation for the Qt::YAxis does not work and i dont know how to write it correctly. I need this propertys for an animation. Here is what im trying:

--A.h--

```
class myOwnPixmapItem : public QObject, public QGraphicsPixmapItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY (QPointF pos READ pos WRITE setPos)
    Q_PROPERTY (QTransform rot READ rot WRITE setRotation)

public:
    flowNpixmapItem()
};
```

--A.cpp--

```
myItemPosAnim -> setTargetObject (myItem);
myItemTransAnim -> setTargetObject (myItem);

myItemPosAnim -> setStartValue (QPointF (cover0 -> pos()));
myItemTransAnim -> setStartValue (QTransform::rotate (0, Qt::YAxis));
```

Comment: Explain how it "does not work." Does it not compile? Not link? Not rotate at all? Or roate the wrong direction? etc.

Comment: Sry i forgot. It tells me "cannot call member function 'QTransform::rotate' without object. But i have set an object (myItem) in myItemTransAnim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `QTransform::rotate` is a non-static member function, meaning that this syntax can only be used to refer a function (*function pointer*), not to *call* the function.

The method `QPropertyAnimation::setStartValue` takes a value (not a function) as its argument, so in your case a QTransform value. `QTransform::rotate(...)` (with arguments) is no value, indeed, it can't be compiled because the compiler thinks you want to call the static method with the given arguments.

So you probably want this:

```
myItemPosAnim -> setTargetObject (myItem);
myItemTransAnim -> setTargetObject (myItem);

myItemPosAnim -> setStartValue (QPointF (cover0 -> pos()));
QTransform transform;
transform.rotate (0, Qt::YAxis):
myItemTransAnim -> setStartValue (transform);
```

---

But I still see a big problem in your code: You animate a transform, not the rotation itself. Rotation transformation is non-linear, meaning that if you try to animate a transformation from 0° to 180°, you would not get what you want. You would rather get a scaling animation, because 180° rotation equals scaling the coordinate system by factor -1. This is because scaling *is* a linear transformation, and QPropertyAnimation interpolates between the start and end value, so "the middle between start and end" is calculated using `0.5 * start + 0.5 * end`, which is *not* what you want for rotation matrices.

Since the rotation of QGraphicsItems is of type `qreal` anyway, just use this type:

```
Q_PROPERTY (double rot READ rot WRITE setRotation)
```

You should then use this like this:

```
myItemPosAnim -> setTargetObject (myItem);
myItemTransAnim -> setTargetObject (myItem);

myItemPosAnim -> setStartValue (QPointF (cover0 -> pos()));
myItemTransAnim -> setStartValue (0.0);
```

Comment: hmm. what you mean "within the code of setRotationX"? Currently im working on it but i get an compiler-error in some moc_files that want to tell me "rotX and setRotationX was not declared in this scope"

Comment: Hm, I just realised that the method setRotation already exists and has type qreal, not QTransform. Specifying an axis in 2D rotation doesn't make any sense either, so you should be fine by just removing the X from the names in the Q_PROPERTY. I changed my answer.

Comment: I had removed the X at my last exercisis but i still get this error that "rot is not declared in this scope". So why? I changed "rot" in my Q_PROPERTY too and set em up in my code with myItemTransAnim -> setPropertyName ("rot");

Comment: You defined `rot` as the "read function", so your class has to have a function with the signature: `qreal myOwnPixmapItem::rot()`. Which doesn't seem to be the case. But there is already a `rotation()` function provided by QGraphicsItem, so just changing rot in rotation should work.

Comment: Just to be clear: the `rot` after the type in Q_PROPERTY is the property name, and can thus still be named as you want to. You refer it in the QPropertyAnimation as a string. But the name after READ has to be an existing function, so you should rename this into rotation, because `rotation()` is the read function you want to use.